# Supervised Learning for User Behavior over Time

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I want to use machine learning to identify the signature of a user who converts to a subscriber of a website given their behavior over time.

Let's say my website has 6 different features which can be used before subscribing and users can convert to a subscriber at any time.

For a given user I have stats which represent the intensity on a continuous range of that user's interaction with features 1-6 on a daily basis so:

- D1: f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6
- D2: f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6
- D3: f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6
- D4: f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6

Let's say on day 5, the user converts.

What machine using algorithms would help me identify which are the most common patterns in feature usage which lead to a conversion?

(I know this is a super basic classification question, but I couldn't find a good example using longitudinal data, where input vectors are ordered by time like I have)

---

To develop the problem further, let's assume that each feature has 3 intensities at which the user can interact (H, M, L).

We can then represent each user as a string of states of interaction intensity. So, for a user:

- LLLLMM LLMMHH LLHHHH

Would mean on day one they only interacted significantly with features 5 and 6, but by the third day they were interacting highly with features 3 through 6.

### N-gram Style

I could make these states words and the lifetime of a user a sentence.  (Would probably need to add a "conversion" word to the vocabulary as well)

If I ran these "sentences" through an n-gram model, I could get the likely future state of a user given his/her past few state which is somewhat interesting.  But, what I really want to know the most common sets of n-grams that lead to the conversion word.  Rather than feeding in an n-gram and getting the next predicted word, I want to give the predicted word and get back the 10 most common n-grams (from my data) which would be likely to lead to the word.

Amaç Herdağdelen suggests identifying n-grams to practical n and then counting how many n-gram states each user has.  Then correlating with conversion data (I guess no conversion word in this example).  My concern is that there would be too many n-grams to make this method practical. (if each state has 729 possibilities, and we're using trigrams, thats a lot of possible trigrams!)

Alternatively, could I just go thru the data logging the n-grams which led to the conversion word and then run some type of clustering on them to see what the common paths are to a conversion?

### Survival Style

Suggested by Iterator, I understand the analogy to a survival problem, but the literature here seems to focus on predicting time to death as opposed to the common sequence of events which leads to death.  Further, when looking up the Cox Proportional Hazard model, I found that it does not event accommodate variables which change over time (its good for differentiating between static attributes like gender and ethnicity)- so it seems very much geared toward a different question than mine.

### Decision Tree Style

This seems promising though I can't completely wrap my mind around how to structure the data.  Since the data is not flat, is the tree modeling the chance of moving from one state to another down the line and when it leads to conversion or not?  This is very different than the decision tree data literature I've been able to find.

Also, need clarity on how to identify patterns which lead to conversion instead a models predicts likely hood of conversion after a given sequence.

Comment: Note: added statistics tag.  It's a classification problem, but somewhat more akin to a survival analysis problem.  I didn't tag it as survival-analysis, though, because that might scare off a good fraction of the SO crowd.  I also recommend posting to the stats.SE site (Cross Validated).  On SO, an algorithmic answer may be expected, on stats.SE, you may get a more statistically inclined answer.

Comment: Should the sentence "...interaction with features 1-5 on a daily basis..." be rewritten to replace "1-5" with "1-6", in line with the sentence before and the table after?

Comment: N-grams are a sequence of state changes, but are entirely serial in nature.  A decision tree is able to do state changes but without the restriction of one-dimensional embeddings (as either characters or words are).  The math would take some time to explain, but a decision tree is always superior to coding things as a sequence of states because it includes the same modelspace and more.

Comment: Your features don't seem to change throughout the days.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, [hidden markov models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) may be a suitable solution to your problem. The features on your site would constitute the alphabet, and you can use the sequence of interactions as positive or negative instances depending on whether a user finally subscribed or not. I don't have a guess about what the number of hidden states should be, but finding a suitable value for that parameter is part of the problem, after all.

As a side note, positive instances are trivial to identify, but the fact that a user has not subscribed so far doesn't necessarily mean s/he won't. You might consider to limit your data to sufficiently old users.

I would also consider converting the data to fixed-length vectors and apply conceptually simpler models that could give you some intuition about what's going on. You could use [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ngram) (consecutive interaction sequences of length n).

As an example, assuming that the interaction sequence of a given user ise "f1,f3,f5", "f1,f3,f5" would constitute a 3-gram (trigram). Similarly, for the same user and the same interaction sequence you would have "f1,f3" and "f3,f5" as the 2-grams (bigrams). In order to represent each user as a vector, you would identify all n-grams up to a practical n, and count how many times the user employed a given n-gram. Each column in the vector would represent the number of times a given n-gram is observed for a given user.

Then -- probably with the help of some suitable normalization techniques such as [pointwise mutual information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information) or [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) -- you could look at the correlation between the n-grams and the final outcome to get a sense of what's going on, carry out [feature selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) to find the most prominent sequences that users are involved in, or apply classification methods such as nearest neighbor, support machine or naive Bayes to build a predictive model.

Comment: A few issues: 1: HMMs are for finite, discrete spaces.  The OP hasn't stated whether the features are for discrete spaces.  2: n-grams and tf.idf are information representation methods, not predictive models.  3: Feature selection is a process undertaken in the context of fitting a model, not typically mentioned as "do feature selection *or* fit a model...".

Comment: 1) You are right. OP doesn't explicitly say the features are discrete -- that was my assumption. If the features are continuous (e.g., the intensity of interaction) then he would have to discretize the features based on a threshold to apply HMM.

2) You are right saying that n-grams and tf-idf are not predictive models -- though I haven't said that they are?

Comment: 3) I disagree. You can use feature selection for explanatory purposes and the model you use for feature selection doesn't have to be same you will apply for predictive purposes (e.g., PCA with dimension reduction or mutual information wouldn't be practical for predictive analysis, but it could help OP to understand which features are important and give insight about the relation between interaction and subscription.

Comment: Regarding #3, just read the first sentence of the Wikipedia entry.  :)  Sure, he could go and do something unsupervised, but the question title is "Supervised learning..."  ;-)

Comment: Thank you both for your thoughtful answers!  I wish that I had a better understanding of the field so that I could give a better thanks ;)

So, the feature stats I have actually are continuous, but I could discretize them if that would be helpful.

I'm now going to spend the next few days researching and wrapping my head around some options you guys posed and I will report back.

Comment: You're welcome! If the ordering of feature interactions is important you might consider discretization, but now, I doubt that this is your case. If you (want to) represent the users simply as a 6-dimensional vector of real values, you could use any convenient supervised model like naive Bayes, SVM, logistic regression, etc. All my suggests about the n-grams were based on my assumption that the order in which the user interacts with the features was important.

Comment: @iterator OP's case also involves UX. Just because he asks about supervised learning shouldn't keep us from recommending ways that would help him to identify -- and maybe improve -- the important features that lead to subscription behavior. After all, it's not just about prediction, but also understanding the underlying dynamics. If you have a suggestion to call "the process of identifying salient features" something other than feature selection, I'd be open to use it.

Comment: I definitely think the order of the the feature interactions is important.

The N-grams actually seems pretty promising...but seems like there is some art in figuring out the # of intensity levels per feature first.

Comment: Please see notes on n-gram approach in revised question :)

Comment: The high number of n-grams shouldn't be problem. You have only 18 (6x3) features and a few thousand n-grams would be manageable -- especially with filtering (e.g., PMI or another weighting mechanism could help you to get rid of unrelated n-grams). My main concern with this method is how you will incorporate the inter-day relations. If you lump all days together you will get one undifferentiated record of interactions. I have the impression that you want to capture the change in dynamics from one day to another. Is that correct?

Comment: A clarification: When I say n-gram I mean the sequence of interactions of user on a given day. For example, with binary interaction variables F1 F4 F1 F1 F1 F4 F5 F2 F4 F5 would be the 10 interactions a user was involved in on a given day with the given order. You can use n-grams to represent sequences like these as a fixed-length vector.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather like a survival analysis problem: over time the user will convert or will may drop out of the population, or will continue to appear in the data and not (yet) fall into neither camp.  For that, you may find the Cox proportional hazards model useful.

If you wish to pursue things from a different angle, namely one more from the graphical models perspective, then a Kalman Filter may be more appealing.  It is a generalization of HMMs, suggested by @AmaçHerdağdelen, which work for continuous spaces.

For ease of implementation, I'd recommend the survival approach.  It is the easiest to analyze, describe, and improve.  After you have a firm handle on the data, feel free to drop in other methods.

Comment: am I missing something about how to properly implement the survival approach?  Please see my concerns in revised question above.

Comment: Yes.  The hazard rate is analogous to the conversion rate.  Cox is but one method, and the use of covariates is pretty standard, even time-varying ones.  The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_models) is a decent starting point, though it may be a bit heavier in statistics than you're looking to address at the moment.  If you want a very simple model, a decision tree would do and it is quite interpretable.

Answer (score 0):

Other than Markov chains, I would suggest decision trees or Bayesian networks. Both of these would give you a likely hood of a user converting after a sequence.

I forgot to mention this earlier. You may also want to take a look at the Google PageRank algorithm. It would help you account for the user completely disappearing [not subscribing]. The results of that would help you to encourage certain features to be used. [Because they're more likely to give you a sale]

Comment: thanks for your repsonse!

I thought through how I would approach decision trees and put some notes in revised question.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ngramm is most promising approach, because all sequnce in data mining are treated as elements depndent on few basic steps(HMM, CRF, ACRF, Markov Fields) So I will try to use classifier based on 1-grams and 2 -grams.